# adventurous vs fearless

Tags: difference

> Kenosha County policeman Dan Ruth, who was at the scene of the accident, told reporters he hasn't witnessed an act more **heroic** than Jill's in his 18 years on the job.

So what does Dan Ruth think of Jill?
A. Adventurous.
B. Persistent.
C. Fearless.
D. Cool-headed.

I can't tell the difference between adventurous and fearless. They both seem to mean courageous.

Answer (score 1):

"Fearles" fits best.

The difficulty here is that "heroic" can mean all of A,B,C, and D. So the meaning of the word "Heroic" can't help much.

Think about the nature of the act.  Jill wasn't going on an adventure. This doesn't seem to have been something that required a long effort (so the sense "determined" doesn't fit). But she did do something brave, and another word for brave is "fearless".  Cool-headed also works, but is less close to the simple sense of "brave and determined" that heroic has.